# JS alert not playing once per session

Tags: javascript, html

I want an alert that plays if the user visits my website for the first time or if its their first time for a set amount of time. I have a function that checks if its the first visit then sends the alert. But it's not playing.

index.html

```
<script src="alert.js"></script>
```

alert.js

```
sessionStorage.setItem('firstVisit', '1');
function welcome(){
    if (!sessionStorage.getItem('firstVisit') === "1"){
        alert('yeet');
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to call the "welcome()" method.

Comment: When are you doing `sessionStorage.setItem('firstVisit', '1');`?

Comment: On every page load you are saying firstvisit = '1' and then if firstvisit is not '1' show alert. So how is it ever going to show the alert? firstvisit is always '1'.

Answer (score 1):

You're only defining `welcome()`; you aren't calling it.  Also, you're setting it every time, so it's always true.  Try setting it only if it's not set yet:

```
function welcome(){
    if (!sessionStorage.getItem('firstVisit')){
        sessionStorage.setItem('firstVisit', '1');
        alert('yeet');
    }
}
welcome();
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jmbldwn/24e1scp6/4/